# Passar parametro javascript para uma pagina php por um botao

Tags: php, ajax, html5

Estou precisando deletar um registro no banco pelo id, estou exibindo minha tabela com os registros por meio do ajax e jquery, porem preciso de um botao que exclua pelo id do registro, ja criei a pagina deleta.php (funciona) porem nao consigo passar o id para o php, segue o ajax que carrega a tebela:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('#tabela').empty(); //Limpando a tabela
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',        //Definimos o método HTTP usado
        dataType: 'json',   //Definimos o tipo de retorno
        url: 'getDados.php',//Definindo o arquivo onde serão buscados os dados
        success: function(dados){
            for(var i=0;dados.length>i;i++){
                //Adicionando registros retornados na tabela

                $('#tabela').append('<tr><td>'+dados[i].nome+'</td><td>'+dados[i].endereco+'</td><td>'+dados[i].telefone+'</td><td><button id="apagar" onload="confirm_delete('+dados[i].id+')">Excluir</td></tr>');

            }
        }
    });
});
$('apagar').click(function(){
                    window.location.href='excluir.php?id='+dados[i].id;
                })
```

Comment: Testa `window.location.href='excluir.php?id=' + this.id;` pois o `this` é o botão clicado nessa função.

Comment: não deu certo, tenho que passa o id tbm no $('#tabela')??

Answer (score 3):

O teu código está incompleto, não vejo onde tens a função `confirm_delete` e o seletor `$('apagar')` está errado.

Mesmo que fosse `$('#apagar')` estaria errado por causa de delegação de eventos e porque os IDs têm de ser unicos. Sugiro passares o `id` e o `this` a `confirm_delete` e usar ajax para apagar e remover a linha no `success`.

Muda também o `onload` para `onclick`, acho que é isso que queres, quando fôr clicado.

Ficaria assim:

```js
function confirm_delete(btn, id) {
    var apagar = confirm('Quer mesmo apagar?');
    if (apagar) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'excluir.php',
        data: {id: id},
        success: function() {
          $(btn).closest('tr').remove();
        }
      });
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#tabela').empty(); //Limpando a tabela
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post', //Definimos o método HTTP usado
    dataType: 'json', //Definimos o tipo de retorno
    url: 'getDados.php', //Definindo o arquivo onde serão buscados os dados
    success: function(dados) {
      var $tabela = $('#tabela');
      for (var i = 0; dados.length > i; i++) {
        $tabela.append('<tr><td>' + dados[i].nome + '</td><td>' + dados[i].endereco + '</td><td>' + dados[i].telefone + '</td><td><button onclick="confirm_delete(this, ' + dados[i].id + ')">Excluir</td></tr>');

      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59118/discussion-on-answer-by-sergio-passar-parametro-javascript-para-uma-pagina-php-p)

Answer (score 0):

Na parte:

```
$('apagar').click(function(){ window.location.href='excluir.php?id='+dados[i].id; })
```

Você não conseguirá acessar as informações da variável **dados** pois ela está disponível apenas dentro do scopo da função **success** passada como parâmetro no ajax.

Seu seletor para o botão de apagar provavelmente está errado caso esteja tentando selecionar por id(#) ou class(.).

Uma solução simples para o seu código seria colocar um atributo cod com o valor do id no botão apagar, e assim quando clicar você seleciona o valor do atributo.

```
$('.apagar').click(function(){ window.location.href='excluir.php?id='+$(this).attr('cod'); })
```

Para que eu possa lhe dar uma resposta mais precisa você poderia disponibilizar o restante do código.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/yr2aezw4/1 - tenho o htm e o ajax